# Wireless router setup for 1-1 NAT

Tags: networking, router, nat, static-ip

**What I have:**

- A linksys router [WAG160N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/AE/en/products/WAG160N) with firmware version 2
- A "pool" of 5 external static IP's provided by my ISP 213.xx.xxx.n

  - All the required configuration values for the static IPs such as (Subnet Mask, Gateway and static DNS 1, 2, 3)

---

**Current WAN Configuration:**

- Encapsulation: *RFC 2364 PPPoA*
- Multiplexing: *VC*
- QoS type: *UBR*
- DSL modulation: *MultiMode*

---

**What's connected to the network:**

- 1 x Server (That I want to make available to the outside)
- 5 x Desktops with static internal IP's, such as 192.168.0.xx
- 2 x Network printers, also with internal static IP's
- 2 x Laptops
- 1 x NAS (Network Attached Storage) also on static IP

---

**What I want to do:**

I would like to make the server available from outside the network, for example from your house. The problem is that Im not really sure how to do this. I have tried following the steps on the [instruction manual](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&login=1&app=search&vw=1&articleid=3979) in Linksys but they do not seem to work, once I set it up as shown bellow, I loose internet and all hell breaks loose.

Going into further detail, I would prefer if the network is changed as little as possible, by this I mean that all the computers stay networked within eachother and only the server is accessible from the outside the network.

---

**What I need HELP with:**

I have read around that it is possible to set a 1-1 NAT *(I know where it is in the menu but have no clue what it does...)* so that I can NAT a single public IP directly to a single private IP (in our case the server). But please, How do I do that? Or maybe an alternative?

Comment: 1:1 NAT Maps a single public IP to a single Private IP instead of the standard public IP to multiple private IPs. This way you can have a server accessible both publicly and privately as well as have it still behind a firewall. This requires that you have multiple public IPs, one for the 1:1 NAT and one for the standard NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to set up 1-1 NAT on your type of router or if it even supports having multiple IP's

But here is the way I do it (basicly using NAT-loopback instead of 1-1 NAT

I have (same as you) 5 IP's and everything hookedup to a Zyxel Zywall USG 100 (professional router/firewall)
After that I have:
- 5-6 private computers (in the private zone)
- 2 physical servers (in the server zone)
- 9 virtual servers (in the server zone)

1 IP is set for my router to use as gateway (so all outgoing connections are running trough here)

But for incoming traffic I use NAT loopback routing with protocol: ANY
this means for my settings:
- original: xxx.xxx.79.43
- mapped: 192.168.x.xxx
- Port mapping: ANY

This I have set-up for my mail server, since it uses a lot of different ports and basicly just has enough importance.
So when you connect with xxx.xxx.79.43 on any port it will go to my mailserver
and since nat-loopback is enabled, it also responds on the same incoming IP

But my router also allows me to override by making a more specific setting
for example for acces to my remote desktop server...
So in this setting I do tell that port 3389 will go to a different server...

This is usefull because instead of dedicating an entire IP to one server, You can still use the IP for a different server...